# Django filters objects from different model

Tags: django

These are my Django models:

```
class Videos(models.Model):

    Title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False, help_text='video title')
    Description = models.TextField(null=True, unique=False, blank=True)
    Tags = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=False, blank=True)
    Category = models.CharField("Category", max_length=32, default='28', choices=CATEGORIES, null=False, blank=False)
    Language = models.CharField("Language", max_length=32, default='EN', choices=LANGUAGES, null=False, blank=False)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='videos/', null=True, blank=False, validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['mp4'])] )
    Playlist = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False)

    title_gen = models.BooleanField(default=False)



class TitleVideo(models.Model):
    video = models.ForeignKey(Videos, related_name='video_id', null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    converted = models.BooleanField(
        default=False, help_text='video has ben converted (True | False)')

    publicato = models.BooleanField(
        default=False, help_text='video has ben published (True | False)')
```

I need to get all Videos which have TitleVideo.converted = false and Videos.title_gen =True, how I can do this ?

Comment: There can be  multiple TitelVideos per Videos (your naming s quite off, particularly the related_name). So every Video (why plural model name?) can have a mixture ofconverted and unverted TitleVideos

Comment: @schwobaseggl yes can be multiple titles per video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try with:

```
from django.db.models import Q
```

would result in

```
Video.objects.filter(Q(title_gen=True) & Q(video_id__converted=False))
```